# Which type of Xero application should we use?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, xero-api

We are creating an integration application which will sync data between Dynamics CRM and Xero. We are now at the stage where we need to decide which type of application we should use to connect to Xero and perform operations.

The application will be used by multiple Xero Customers. So our application should serve multiple Xero users.

We will have web api which will call on Dynamics CRM events(Create, Update Contact etc.) and will update the data in Xero. 
So our web api should connect to Xero and perform operations in Xero. We tried using Public application but it generates the token that is valid for 30 minutes. The web api should communicate to Xero without any time limitation.

Please suggest how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should begin developing your integration using a public application, and get in touch with Xero to register for becoming a partner application (which will give you the ability to request long-term tokens). The process is documented here: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/auth-and-limits/partner-applications